# What's the benefit of buying municipal bonds on the secondary market?

Tags: united-states, bonds, municipal-bonds

"Buy munis!", they say... "they're tax exempt!", they say... but **are they?**  It looks like you're paying income tax on most of the Yield To Maturity (since interest rates have gone up so much, many older bonds are selling at a significant discount), even though the picayune interest payments are tax exempt.

I ask this, because according to page 4 of [Tax Treatment of Bond Premium and Discount](https://www.bairdwealth.com/globalassets/pdfs/help/tax-treatment-bond-premium-and-discount.pdf):

> **MARKET DISCOUNT – TAX-EXEMPT BONDS**

> Tax-exempt bonds purchased with market discount after April 30, 1993 are subject to the same rules as taxable discount bonds
>
> • If the discount is accreted each year – **The accreted discount is treated as ordinary interest income** and is subject to federal income tax. This accreted discount is **taxable despite the fact that the bond itself is considered a tax exempt bond**.
>
> • If the discount is not accreted annually – **Any gain attributed to the market discount** that was not accreted is **subject to federal tax as ordinary interest income when the bond is disposed of**. Any gain beyond that amount is
> taxed as a capital gain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, capital gains from the sale or redemption of municipal bonds is taxable; it's just the interest that is tax-free.   Even then it's typically only state-tax-free *in your own state*. States often tax the interest on municipal bonds to owners that do not reside in the state.

To be fair, it's still a benefit, it's just not as blanket a benefit as "Munis are tax free" would lead you to believe.